# Why does my Lubuntu Software Centre only show installed apps?

Tags: software-center, lubuntu

The title is self explanatory but here is a big screenshot to emphasize what I mean

[image: Lubuntu Software Centre]

As you can see I have the Get Software tab open with the all section selected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't replicate your case. I get everything as per normal. Perhaps, you could reinstall and see if that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jokerdino suggested I reinstalled the software centre from synaptic and all is well. I think actually I could have gotten away with doing a

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lubuntu-software-center`

would have worked as well.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing a program's title in the search field and you should be able to find new programs. Lubuntu's software center is not the same as in Ubuntu, therefore it is possible that you might face such difficulties. If it's the program's fault, you could try installing the Ubuntu Software Center (this is a workaround though, not a fix for the Lubuntu Software center).

Also, you may be interested in reading this for further information: [click here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1842575)

If you don't want to install another software center, I would suggest to reinstall Lubuntu - that is a "nuclear-bomb" approach though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if LSC updates its package information when it starts, but it definitely checks what's already there. If it doesn't automatically update, then it may need to be manually spurred by either running your Update Manager and checking for new packages or manually updating the package info by using `sudo apt-get update` from the command line. Then launch LSC to see if it has other programs available for you. All this assumes you have access to the internet, because without that there's not really a way for the system to check for new packages.